# gjson: cast json array as a slice

Tags: json, go

Using the gjson package, casting gjson.Result objects to a string is simple `j.Get("str").String()` but I can't figure out how to cast an object to a string slice.  E.g.:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/tidwall/gjson"
)

func main() {
    j := `{"array": ["a","b","c"]}`
    gj := gjson.Parse(j).Get("array").Value()
    for k, v := range gj {
        fmt.Println(k, v)
    }
}
```

This fails as Value() casts the array as an Interface which cannot be ranged over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the API docs, the result of `Parse().Get()` is a [`Result()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/tidwall/gjson#readme-result-type) type. The package supports a variety of handy functions that work on the type. e.g. you just need the [`Array()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/tidwall/gjson#Result.Array) method

```golang
func main() {
    j := `{"array": ["a","b","c"]}`
    gj := gjson.Parse(j).Get("array").Array()
    for k, v := range gj {
        fmt.Println(k, v)
    }
}
```

Note that, the package works with the types specific to JSON and not `Go` in general.

In JSON context the returned value is an *array* type. So if you were to need a `[]string` type, create your own, using the [`Result.Str`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/tidwall/gjson#Result) attribute

```golang
func main() {
    j := `{"array": ["a","b","c"]}`
    var result []string
    gj := gjson.Parse(j).Get("array").Array()
    for _, v := range gj {
        result = append(result, v.Str)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This returns an array of gjson.Result objects rather than a slice of the object content.

Comment: @SteveCrook The return type of `Array()` is a slice type of your desired values, which you can use

Comment: You are correct.  My real-world code has a function where I wanted to return a []string.  This doesn't work because `.Array()` returns a []gjson.Result object.

Comment: @SteveCrook: Yeah, thats right. All you need is to create a slice of string out of it

Comment: If you know the final type you want to unmarshal to, it may be better to just use the standard library's `json.Unmarshal` and pass in a `struct { Items []string }` typed value.